Reference Paths in GitLab CI Rules generates error: "paths should be an array of strings"
I want to reference paths in a rule so I can reuse this reference in multiple rules.
My approach is as follows:
.my-paths:
    paths:
        - path/to/file.1
        - path/to/file.2

.my-rule:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
          changes:
              compare_to: "refs/heads/main"
              paths:
                  - !reference [.my-paths, paths]
                  - path/to/file.3
                  - path/to/file.4

my-job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - 'echo "Do Something!"'
    rules:
        - !reference [.my-rule, rules]

Unfortunately I get the error message: "jobs:my-job:rules:rule:changes paths should be an array of strings"
What am I doing wrong. A similiar approach with using the whole rule section works perfectly fine.
Reference: nest-reference-tags

This reference expansion results in a nested list, which is not supported in rules:changes:paths:. Note that the documentation you linked only mentions script, before_script and after_script explicitly.

The same thing works for rules, scripts, etc. but not working for paths. There is a open ticket for this.
The workaround is using Anchors:
.my-paths: &my_paths
    - path/to/file.1
    - path/to/file.2
    - path/to/file.3
    - path/to/file.4

.my-rule:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
          changes:
              compare_to: "refs/heads/main"
              paths: *my_paths
                  

my-job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - 'echo "Do Something!"'
    rules:
        - !reference [.my-rule, rules]


Tried with anchors before got the same error since .my-rule should contain the my-path AND some individual paths entries. In you example it is only the anchor (see example in question).
